# How to receive game center Multiplayer data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center

I am trying to implement game center real time multiplayer in my sprite kit game in Swift, and I can't seem to find any tutorials that display how to do this in Swift. So far I have authenticated the player and done the matchmaking, but when Receiving data I found that you have to use a delegate method to do it. I found this sort of code in Objective C:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID{}
```

First of all, how would I convert this to Swift, and second I read that this is automatically called. I don't really get how it works, and would it call if you put it in a `SKScene class`?

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!